# Conditional statement with join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two datasets, df1 and df2, where I would like to join the two and then **apply a condition that if there are more than one duplicate rows in the host column**, take only that one row (to avoid duplicates). I will be joining df1 and df2 ON df1.version = df2.name AND ON  df1.date = df2.date

conditions: purpose should = 'hi' or purpose should = 'cat'

df1

```
version host    date                                      
pat     a16     12/1/2019   
fam     a16     12/1/2019   
emp     a16     12/1/2019   
dan     a16     12/1/2019
```

df2

```
name    purpose  date
pat     hi       12/1/2019
fam     cat      12/1/2019
hello   dog      12/1/2019
dan     bird     12/1/2019
```

Here are the join results:

```
version host    date                 name    purpose       date                      
pat     a16     12/1/2019            pat     hi            12/1/2019
fam     a16     12/1/2019            fam     cat           12/1/2019
```

**DESIRED**

```
version host    date                 name    purpose       date                      
pat     a16     12/1/2019            pat     hi            12/1/2019
```

**DOING**

```
select    df1.version, df1.host, df1.date, df2.name, df2.purpose, df2.date
from      df1
left join df2
on        df1.version = df2.name  AND
          df1.date    = df2.date
where     df2.purpose = 'hi' OR df2.purpose = 'cat'
```

I think I have to implement an IF THEN statement within SQL. The above statement only does the join but it does not get rid of the consecutive duplicate host rows. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: `take only the first row` ... what defines what the "first" row is here?

Comment: add `and row_id =1`.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate row ?

Comment: I wish to remove any duplicate rows from the 'host' column

Comment: In your sample output, yes there are 2 rows with ```a16``` as the host value, but what business logic decides on whether you choose the row with ```version = pat``` or the row with ```version=fam``` ?    That is pretty crucial to suggesting a valid solution.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I just need the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply ROW_NUMBER() function and rank the rows to remove duplicate rows. But, as you are ranking by date, purpose row could either be `hi` or `cat`. If you want to specifically pick one of them as first, you have to apply ORDER BY accordingly.

```sql
;with cte_df as
(
select df1.version, df1.host,df1.date, df2.name, df2.purpose, df2.date as df2date
,row_number() over(partition by df1.host order by df1.date) as rnk
FROM df1
inner join df2 
on df1.version = df2.name and df1.date = df2.date
where df2.purpose in ('hi','cat')
)
SELECT * from cte_df WHERE rnk =1
```

**Without_CTE, using derived table**

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM
(
select df1.version, df1.host,df1.date, df2.name, df2.purpose, df2.date as df2date
,row_number() over(partition by df1.host order by df1.date) as rnk
FROM df1
inner join df2 
on df1.version = df2.name and df1.date = df2.date
where df2.purpose in ('hi','cat')
) AS T
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way to remove rows when there is a duplicate in the 'host' column?

Comment: yes. that is what taken care in this query. we are partition by host and generating row_number. So, for the first host row, rank will be 1. Only it is selected in the end

Comment: ok I will try this. Do I have to use cte? (common table expression?)

Comment: @Lynn, you don't need CTE. You can use derived table. I have added that solution as well to the answer

Comment: ah ok thank you kindly I am working this out now

Comment: Hi I have this error in SQL Fiddle : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by df1.host order by df1.date) as rnk FROM df1 inner join df2 on df1' at line 8 -  I am researching this

Comment: Share your fiddle link so that we can help you on it

Comment: @Lynn, you have mentioned it as sql server. fiddle is against mySQL

Comment: ok- I am trying to test this out in sql fiddle- ok that is fine. I will create this in sql server